# Datagridview analyses in R-system in c++/cli

Tags: r, datagridview, c++-cli

I have datagridview with text data in visual studio that get analysis with R-system and I wanted to know from where should I start. Should I export datagridview before analyses or write some script in R-system or there is some plugin with that in visual studio ?